# Unsatisifed GET request Jasmine with angularJS for asynch service calls

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am getting Unsatisified GET request error message when i run my jasmine test case.I am trying to test my service.
The structure is:

```
describe('should test Static Quotes List functionality', function () {

            it('should check list of static quotes is not null', function () {

                //ARRANGE 

                var url = CONFIG.autoApiBaseUrl + 'api/quotesconfig';

                httpBackend.expect('GET', url).respond(staticQuotesData);

                //ACT
                retrievequoteService.getStaticQuotes().then(function (data) {
                    //ASSERT
                    expect(data).not.toBeNull();
                    expect(data.length).toEqual(1);
                });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    httpBackend.flush();
                }, 100);

            });
        });
```

And my service file is:

```
  function getStaticQuotes() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        retrievequoteResource.getStaticQuotes().$promise.then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Can you please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks.
Sajesh

Comment: It would greatly help if you provided the details of the test failure

Comment: Also, you appear to be using a deferred anti-pattern. Your service should just `return retrievequoteResource.getStaticQuotes().$promise;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil. details are: Unsatisfied requests: GET /onlinesalesapp-auto/api/quotesconfig
    at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation (http://localhost/onlinesalesweb/assets/vendor/AicAngular-1.5/angular-mocks-1.5.0.js:1559:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/onlinesalesweb/tests/unitTest/products/retrievequote/retrievequote.service.spec.js:25:29)

Comment: First thing I'd do is remove that `setTimeout`. No idea why you're using that in a test

Comment: initially i did not had that setTimeout but then i was getting Error: No pending request to flush ! so i thought there is a delay before the actual request is happening

Comment: No, there is no delay unless your code adds one

Comment: The real problem here is that you appear to be testing two things which is not what a unit test is for. If you're testing `retrievequoteService`, then you should be mocking `retrievequoteResource`

Comment: Not sure why the test is failing, i tried your suggestion but it still doesnt work, Phil any idea what should i do to make it work, all my service test cases is on hold because of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to

```
spyOn(retrievequoteResource, "getStaticQuotes").and.returnValue({ $promise: q.when(staticQuotesData) });

                //ACT

                var result;

                var promise = retrievequoteService.getStaticQuotes();
                promise.then(function (result) {
                    expect(result).not.toBeNull();
                    expect(result.length).toEqual(1);
                });

                $rootScope.$digest();
```